# Maya Python Create joints Hierachy

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to create o hierarchy of joints for a skeleton in maya python. And I'm doing this

```
def makeSkelet(args):

    helperSkelet('Root_Locator', 'root_Joint')
    helperSkelet('Pelvis_Locator', 'pelvis_Joint')
    helperSkelet('Spine_Locator', 'spine_Joint')
    helperSkelet('Spine01_Locator', 'spine01_Joint')
    helperSkelet('Spine02_Locator', 'spine02_Joint')
    helperSkelet('Neck_Locator', 'neck_Joint')
    helperSkelet('Head_Locator', 'head_Joint')
    mc.select(cl=True)
    helperSkelet('ArmL_Locator', 'armL_joint')
    helperSkelet('ElbowL_Locator', 'elbowL_Joint')
    helperSkelet('HandL_Locator', 'handL_Joint')
    mc.select(cl=True)
    helperSkelet('ArmR_Locator', 'armR_joint')
    helperSkelet('ElbowR_Locator', 'elbowR_Joint')
    helperSkelet('HandR_Locator', 'handR_Joint')
    mc.select(cl=True)
    helperSkelet('HipL_Locator', 'hipL_joint')
    helperSkelet('KneeL_Locator', 'kneeL_Joint')
    helperSkelet('AnkleL_Locator', 'ankleL_Joint')
    helperSkelet('FootL_Locator', 'footL_Joint')
    mc.select(cl=True)
    helperSkelet('HipR_Locator', 'hipR_joint')
    helperSkelet('KneeR_Locator', 'kneeR_Joint')
    helperSkelet('AnkleR_Locator', 'ankleR_Joint')
    helperSkelet('FootR_Locator', 'footR_Joint')
```

Now this works fine, because the joints must be created in this order. (the helper skelet is a function where i create the joint with the reference to a locator position)

I was wondering if there is a more optimized way to do this considering the order or creation must be kept .

Thank you

Comment: If it works, I can't think of a way to "optimize" it more than it already is. You could, of course compact it into a `list` of joints and loop over the list, but that still won't optimize it more than it already is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "optimize" you mean getting better performace, I agree with what @downshift said.

If what you meant was instead making your code "cleaner" (more general or scalable or simply more pythonic), here's another way you can do the same, which is a bit more compact (and separates the logic from your input):

```
def helperSkeletGroup(group, symmetric=False):
    # quick workaround to capitalize a word, leaving the following letters unchanged
    capitalize = lambda s: s[:1].upper() + s[1:]

    symmetric_group = []
    for elem in group:
        if symmetric:
            symmetric_group.append('{0}R'.format(elem))
            elem = '{0}L'.format(elem)
        # format locators and joints
        loc, joint = '{0}_Locator'.format(capitalize(elem)), '{0}_Joint'.format(elem)
        helperSkelet(loc, joint)
    cmds.select(cl=True)
    if symmetric_group:
        helperSkeletGroup(symmetric_group)

helperSkeletGroup(['root', 'pelvis', 'spine', 'spine01', 'spine02', 'neck', 'head'])
helperSkeletGroup(['arm', 'elbow', 'hand'], True)
helperSkeletGroup(['hip', 'knee', 'ankle', 'foot'], True)
```

This comes with a few advantages:

- it handles symmetry for you
- the code doesn't grow too much, as the number of joints increases
- if at some point you want to change the naming convention for locators and joints, you can do it by changing a single line

Alternatively, you could go with an OOP approach.
Here's an example:

```
class Skeleton:

    def __init__(self):
        self.joint_groups = []

    def add_joint_group(self, group, symmetric=False):
        # quick workaround to capitalize a word, leaving the following letters unchanged
        capitalize = lambda s: s[:1].upper() + s[1:]

        processed, processed_symmetric = [], []
        for elem in group:
            if symmetric:
                processed_symmetric.append('{0}R'.format(elem))
                elem = '{0}L'.format(elem)
            processed.append(('{0}_Locator'.format(capitalize(elem)), '{0}_Joint'.format(elem)))
        self.joint_groups.append(processed)
        if processed_symmetric:
            self.add_joint_group(processed_symmetric)

    def helper_skelet(self, loc, joint):
        # your helper logic goes here
        print loc, joint

    def build(self):
        for group in self.joint_groups:
            for loc, joint in group:
                self.helper_skelet(loc, joint)
            cmds.select(cl=True)

skeleton = Skeleton()
skeleton.add_joint_group(['root', 'pelvis', 'spine', 'spine01', 'spine02', 'neck', 'head'])
skeleton.add_joint_group(['arm', 'elbow', 'hand'], True)
skeleton.add_joint_group(['hip', 'knee', 'ankle', 'foot'], True)

from pprint import pformat
print pformat(skeleton.joint_groups)

skeleton.build()
```

Here the code is a bit longer but it is all contained in a single object, where you could store additional data, which you get only at construction time and which you might need later on.

**EDIT** (to answer @Giakaama's question in the comment):

If you save the class in a separate file `skeleton_class.py`, you can import the class in your main.py (or whatever you want to call it), as such:

`from skeleton_class import Skeleton`

where the lower-case `skeleton_class` refers to your module (read: file) and `Skeleton` is the class itself.
Once you've done that, you can do the same as above:

```
skeleton = Skeleton()
skeleton.add_joint_group(['root', 'pelvis', 'spine', 'spine01', 'spine02', 'neck', 'head'])
skeleton.add_joint_group(['arm', 'elbow', 'hand'], True)
skeleton.build()
```

Comment: Nice, yes I was refering to make the code more "cleaner" :). Thanks for the answers you both.

Comment: If I go with the Class Skeleton, and put that class into another file something like Skeleton.py how can I import it in my main file ? I've tried the empty __init__.py and it's not working :( .

Comment: Just edited the answer with a hint; let me know if that solves your issue. Also, if the `Skeleton` class lives in a subfolder of your `main.py` location, make sure you name the `__init__.py` file properly ;)

Comment: Properly as in ? :)

Comment: I meant with the double underscores before and after the word "init", since you didn't type those. Is it not working for you? If not, can you specify the folder structure you have (where is your skeleton class file, relative to your main)?

Comment: So, I have a headache with classes in separate folders in Maya :) . So:
- In a folder MayaRig - i have a folder named components and in it is the __init__.py and the skeleton.py with the SkeletonClass in it .
I'm trying to import it as from components.skeleton import SkeletonClass and it doesn't work .
The folder with the scripts it's in my dropbox not in maya/scripts

Comment: '__init.py__' I have the dashes but it seems the stackoverflow are taking them out :)

Comment: Fixed it , it seems that I needed to do a import sys and append the path 

sys.path.append('folder') 
now it works ith the from xxx import xxx :)

Comment: if you're trying to source your code from a folder somewhere on your computer, you need to let Maya know where to look. You have a number of ways to do it; have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/maya/7437/maya-python-paths (or simply search for Maya and `userSetup.py` or `PYTHONPATH`). The quick and dirty alternative (I'd suggest it only for temporary testing) is to add on top of your `main.py` something like: `import sys`, `path="/path/to/your/module/"` and `if path not in sys.path: sys.path.append(path)`. After that, you should be able to source your module

Comment: well, apparently you got there before I could hit `Add Comment` :D glad it worked; I'll leave the comment above for completeness and because you might want to go the `PYTHONPATH` or `userSetup.py` way, at some point: you generally do not want explicit paths in your code (ie. if you want to publish it somewhere, deploy it on multiple machines, etc.)

Comment: Lol, so the story so far. It worked for several days, but now it doesn't :))). So I'm making a new file and I just want to import the module from other folder without maya giving an error . It doesn't work :) . Maya is giving ' invalid syntax ' ...

Comment: `invalid syntax` is a Python error, not Maya's. It means there's something wrong in the way you wrote your code. Could you share it anywhere? it'd be quite hard to help otherwise... otherwise, to troubleshoot it yourself you can comment all the code in your `main.py` and then remove comments line by line until the error comes back again. Doing that in Maya can be tedious, though; I'd suggest you test your code with mayapy; see: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-83799297-C629-48A8-BCE4-061D3F275215-htm.html